# python aafigure warning font not found

Tags: python, fonts

I am trying to use the aafigure package in order to render some ASCII diagrams. When I try to test with the command `aafigure sequence.txt -t=png`  I get the following errors :

`WARNING: font not found, using PIL default font
ERROR: Can't output format '=png': PIL doesn't support image format '=png'`

It looks like this [error](http://wiki.asciidoc-aafigure-filter.googlecode.com/hg-history/bcc2135ab4d0ea00052393edfd48bea5e3036c20/asciidoc-aafigure-readme.html) is due to an unrecognised font by `PIL`library. It would be fixed if the error message generates the missing font which in my case (MacOS) is not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

try use

```
aafigure sequence.txt -t png -o test.png
```

reference

https://pythonhosted.org/aafigure/manual.html#usage

Comment: Thanks... What an idiocy.. I will read better the error output next time!